# How to write a test case for component in react-admin demo

Tags: react-admin

Is there any example or guide that how i can write test cases for the https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/dashboard/Dashboard.tsx

How to setup test cases for useVersion and useMediaQuery

Comment: Am too need the answer for this. @marmelab